# IntelliJ unable to run JUnit5 tests with JDK 11

Tags: intellij-idea, migration, junit5, openjdk-11

I upgraded the JVM on my system from JDK 8 to JDK 11 & configured my IntelliJ IDEA (2019.1) to use it.
I am able to compile fine, but can no longer run JUnit5 tests from within the IDE.

I created a basic JUnit test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class UtilsTest {
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {}

    @Test
    void testA {}
}
```

When I run this test with IntelliJ pointing to my JDK 8 install, it runs fine.
If I run this test with IntelliJ pointing to my JDK 11 install, the test fails to run & I get this error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the issue reproduced with IntelliJ IDEA v2020.2.3 (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)?

Comment: @OlgaKlisho yes .. I am running IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3 Community Edition & seeing the issue. 
Also I am running the test using the default JUnit test configuration template & not adding the SplitVerifier vm option

Comment: Please file an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue providing a sample project where the issue is reproduced for you. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Intellij passes maven-surefire-plugin and maven-failsafe-plugin parameters to your Junit.
I got this trouble too. Even if i uncheck boxes in "Intellij -> File -> Settings -> Running Tests", doesn't work.
I removed the .idea folder and all .iml files and reimported the whole project and now, it's working.