Intellij Idea: Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier' While running Junit

Jdk: 17.0.1
Intellij: IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4
OS: Linux.

When I run Junit i see the error

Unrecognized VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'

That argument is not added in any of the configurations or pom.xml. Junits are passed when executed from mvn command line. How can i fix this and run junit from Intellij?
Options tried: Deleted the ide folder and re-opened the project still the same issue.
Expectation is to run Junit without errors from intellij

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64399275/2422776 (there's an answer there, but it has no upvotes and is not accepted)

Tried the answer in that thread by deleting .idea folder it didn’t work
